# Php in Ubuntu 16.04 apache2

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

Php script not running in browser , only showing and downloading that php file in Ubuntu 16.04 . I had already install php 7.0 .

Comment: If your server not started or you have provided file:/// path than such situation will be appears please correct browser location if not, or check server status.

Comment: Did you enable the PHP module for Apache? Which address are you using in your browser?

Comment: file:///var/www/html/mini/home.php is the address and i had already enable the php module and then restart the Apache 2 service

Answer (score 1):

Do you have  `libapache2-mod-php7.0` installed?

Edit:

```
sudo apt-get **install** libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Comment: @user9385507 Restarted your apache afterwards?

Comment: i had restart also but nothing is happen

Comment: Did you run xammp server?